# Drawing application that produces code for QuartzCore, in WYSIWYG style

Tags: iphone, drawing, quartz-graphics

Does any one knows about something like that ?
I find myself drawing the interface in my apps by trying and fixing and i thought that there must be application that can convert my drawings to code.

thanks

shani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at LikeThought's [Opacity](http://likethought.com/opacity/). Naturally, the code it generates is often not perfect, but it is a good starting point for your own optimizations.